# How to group by in Rails use Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model named `Product` , it's attributes `name`, `quantity`

I tried to use ActiveRecord to group by `name` in postgresql database and it was not working

This is errors:

```
  Product Load (53.6ms)  SELECT "".* FROM "products" GROUP BY name
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "products.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

LINE 1: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" GROUP BY name
           ^
=> #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x4d26424>
```

Thank you for any answer!

Comment: What do you want to do with "quantity"? Sum it? Average it? Return the largest value? See [PostgreSQL Aggregate Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html).

Comment: I want to show it , not Sum or Average.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. In SQL, GROUP BY summarizes a set of rows in a single row. Since there are presumably many values of "quantity" in a set, you need to tell PostgreSQL what kind of summary value you want.

Comment: Do you mean order instead of group? Group will return one row per "name", so you need an aggregate function to combine all rows with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to lead you to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group

Here is a example 
For example, if you want to find a collection of the dates orders were created on:

```
  Product.select('name').group("name")
  Product.select('name, sku').group("name, sku")
```

**Note you need a select**

Comment: I don't want to group sku , only name. But I want to have both name and sku. In Mysql can do that , why is postgres not ?